# How to move cursor for items in List in console C#?

Tags: c#, console, generic-collections

I'd appreciate of someone could help to find a mistake.
I printed items of my List in console and i need to move my cursor down, for each item to be highlighted, I've tried like this:

```
foreach (FileSystemInfo fsi in files)
         Console.WriteLine(fsi); //printing the "files" list

Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0); //setting initial place of cursor
while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)  //untill i press escape
{
    switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:   //for Down key
            foreach (FileSystemInfo fsi in files)
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

                // Here's the problem, the cursor goes to the end of the list, 
                // not moving through each item:
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, files.IndexOf(fsi)); 

            }
            break;
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

I'd be grateful for any help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: why the for each in DownArrow ?

Comment: i just need to get the index of each line in console files.IndexOf(fsi)

Comment: curPos hold the IndexOf value!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it goes down the complete list due to the foreach within your case.

I changed your filelist to a list of string for my example

```
var files = new List<string>()
    {
        "File1", "File2", "File3", "File4",
    };

foreach (var fsi in files)
    Console.WriteLine(fsi); //printing the "files" list

// A counter to save the specific position
int cnt = 0;
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cnt);//setting initial place of cursor

// Save the pressed key so you dont need to press it twice
ConsoleKey key;
while ((key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key) != ConsoleKey.Escape)  //untill i press escape
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:   //for Down key
            cnt++;

            if (cnt >= files.Count)
            {
                cnt = files.Count - 1;
            }

            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

            // Here's the problem, the cursor goes to the end of the list, 
            // not moving through each item:
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cnt);

            break;

        case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:   //for Down key
            cnt--;

            if (cnt < 0)
            {
                cnt = 0;
            }

            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

            // Here's the problem, the cursor goes to the end of the list, 
            // not moving through each item:
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cnt);

            break;

    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

The color coding you are trying to do, does not yet work as you want, but I'm sure, you know how to fix it ;-)

Comment: How will i change cursor position then, i mean i change it by files.IndexOf(fsi), should i read all lines in console, and take their indexes?

Answer (score 1):

#### This works

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\");
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0); //setting initial place of cursor
        int curPos = -1;

        if (files.Length > 0)
        {
            curPos = 0;
        }
        ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo;
        while ((keyinfo = Console.ReadKey(true)).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)  //untill i press escape
        {
            switch (keyinfo.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:   //for Down key
                    curPos++;
                    
                        // Here's the problem, the cursor goes to the end of the list, 
                        // not moving through each item:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, curPos);
                        

                    
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                    curPos--;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, curPos);
                    break;
            }
        }
        


    }
```

PS : Do check for curPos bound when pressing Down n Up keys! rest all works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want each stroke on the down arrow key to move down **one** file, in such case change the code to this:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0); //setting initial place of cursor
ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
int index = 0;
while (key != ConsoleKey.Escape)  //untill i press escape
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:   //for Down key
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            index = (index + 1) % files.Count;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, index);
            break;
        }
        key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
}
```

This also fix double reading you had, which casued the user had to press each key twice.